# width of lines in linear layout in percentage

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any option for percentage width in android? I'm trying to set my 2 lines to 40% and text to 20% but i really don't know how to achieve this. i have for now fixed width.

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="14dp"
                android:id="@+id/line2"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/line" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/or"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2.18"
                android:contentDescription="@string/line" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

This is screen from android studio for better understanding : [screen](http://postimg.org/image/5qsyfu5gr/full/)

Comment: Did you try weights for your widgets? That will help

Comment: With the new percent support library, you can now use Percent Layouts. [Check out this link](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `android:layout_weight` for that.
Like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Note that I've added a weight for each element under `LinearLayout` and that I've changed `android:weightSum` in `LinearLayout` itself to 5.

Comment: but layout_width is set to 120 dp and i can't set it to fixed size because it won't be full size on bigger screens, or?

Comment: @mayyyo, please try with layout_width="wrap_content" - Let me know if it works. I don't have the ability to test for Android at my current workplace.

Comment: Last guess: try `layout_width="fill_parent"` instead of `layout_width="wrap_content"`, but only for the lines. If this does not work, I'll delete my answer. Sorry I can't test my own code.

Comment: Just before your answer i tried set layout_width="fill_parent" to linear layout and it works, so not for lines but for parent layout, you can edit your answer and thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate with my answer, which was posted just 1.5 minute before yours :)

Comment: @MarchingHome i thought if this guy duplicate  your code then in your  imageView your code is  'android:layout_width="120dp"' but the answered person code is different. then how did you say it was duplicate

Comment: @Concentrated_Attitude A duplicate does not mean it has to be copied, but that the contents and idea seem to be the same. And yes, I've fixed the 120dp problem now.